# Angular 9 upgrade, SASS fails to build - gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`

Tags: angular, sass, node-gyp

I've upgrade two projects so far with no issue.  After each upgrade I have removed the node_modules directory and rebuilt with yarn.    The prior two projects with pretty much the exact same dependencies (and larger projects) worked with no problem.
However, this project fails with the following trace. I'm entirely baffled at this point after numerous searches and version upgrades.   Can anyone see something stupid I have missed?

```
gyp verb could not find "C:\Python27". checking python launcher
gyp verb check python launcher python executable found: "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"
gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.17
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 12.13.1
gyp verb command install [ '12.13.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "12.13.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 12.13.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 12.13.1
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices\node_modules\node-sass\build
gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\nhust\\.node-gyp\\12.13.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\nhust\\.node-gyp\\12.13.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\nhust\\.node-gyp\\12.13.1\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\nhust\.node-gyp\12.13.1
gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\ProjAngular\\SupervisionServices\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\ProjAngular\SupervisionServices\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72038991/11870285) out. It's a kind of similar problem.

Answer (score -3):

Delete your package-lock.json and run npm install

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer and it doesn't work

Comment: @vsync at the time I had not yet earned the right to comment!