# npm install error code 1failled to build project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I wanted to install npm in my project folder but I always have error. I searched a lot and tried different things like installing  windows-build-tools with yarn and npm but both freezes in the middel. I have also tried to delete node_modules folder but it gives an eeror that it cannot find it afterwards.I reinstalled node and node-ssas but none worked.  I installed python 2.7 and gave the path to node but it seems it wants to download it again. can someone help me what is the problem?

I'm using windows 10
node version 6.14.0
npm 8.3.1
python 2.7
yarn 1.22.17

the latest error is this
ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 '''
 npm ERR! code 1
 npm ERR! path V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass
 npm ERR! command failed
 npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
 npm ERR! Building: C:\programs\node\node.exe 
 V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose -- libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\programs\\node\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node- gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "c:\programs\python27\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded c:\programs\python27\python.exe c:\programs\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `c:\programs\python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.15
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.14.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.14.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64) (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Missing a Windows SDK (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.* or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Some required components are missing, not using this installation
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17134
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:2808) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn c:\programs\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\AndiaFathi\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\AndiaFathi\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\AndiaFathi\\.node-gyp\\16.14.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\AndiaFathi\.node-gyp\16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\programs\\node\\node.exe" "V:\\VOCSensServer\\vocsensuimanager\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd V:\VOCSensServer\vocsensuimanager\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AndiaFathi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-14T13_08_19_585Z-debug-0.log
'''
```

Comment: I don't know what is exact issue. If you have already exist `package-lock.json` then remove it and ty again to install.

Answer (score 3):

You did right for Python as it says `succeeded` after checking for the Python executable. But the problem is that there is no `15.0` directory in Visual Studio 2019 (ENOENT).
You should change the path to `MSBuild.exe`. It should be like:

### v2017

```
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
npm config set msvs_version 2017
```

### v2019

```
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
npm config set msvs_version 2019
```

### v2022

```
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
npm config set msvs_version 2022
```

You can check your npm configuration by using:

```
npm config list
```

I had the same problem and found the solution on [this post](https://pkworlz.com/setting-msbuild-exe-path-with-node/).